# Kernel, Green function and the functional derivative.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

I am pretty new to the subject of differential equations and am reading about Green functions and Kernels for the first time. I am more familiar with functional differentiation and am comfortable with the idea that the functional derivative at a point is given by the Dirac delta function.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x)}=\delta (x-a)
\end{equation}
With $F=f(a)$. I have noticed that this is very similar to a Green function.

My question is:

> Are the above ideas related in a way more than coincidence? In particular functional derivatives, Green functions and Kernels.

My understanding of a Green function is that it is the solution to the inhomogeneous linear ODE while the Kernel is the solution to the homogeneous linear ODE. As you can see it is not extensive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark**

Given a differential operator $L$ we seek the solution $u$ to the inhomogenous ODE

$$L[u(t)] = f(t)$$

The green function of $L$ is $G(x,t)$ satisfying

$$L[G(x,t)] = \delta(x-t)$$

such that our solution $u(t)$ can be expressed as an integral with kernel $G$:

$$u(t) = \int_C{G(x,t)f(x)dx}$$

Over a suitable domain C.

A fantastic book on such methods of solving ODEs is Brian Davies - Integral Transforms and Their Applications, This is a specialised book and only discusses this topic, but i'm sure you have the prerequisites to follow.
Riley Hobbs - Mathematical Methods for physicists is also on I always go back to. It covers a lot so it is expensive and heavy!

Comment: this answers the OP's question in *no* way

Comment: It wasnt meant as an answer but a remark about green functions and a reference to texts covering the topic. I shall edit the response to reflect that